# How to store a float number with a 0 decimal in database

Tags: php, database, floating-point, numbers

I need to store the engine capacity of a car in database and I want to add it like this:

```
2.0, 2.4, 3.0 etc.
```

How can I store the `2.0` or `3.0`?

I tried this column types: float, decimal, double, but nothing works because `2.0` will become `2`, `3.0` will become `3` and so on.

Any idea how can i do this?

One solution would be to make the column `varchar`, but this is not a really good idea.

Comment: A number is a number. `2.0` is the same number as `2.000`, and `2`, and `0000002`, and `0b10`, and any number of other representations. The presentation of `2.0` is a _display_ issue. Format the number into a string at output time with desired radix, desired number of decimals, leading zeroes and whatnot.

Comment: I think it's almost certain that your SQL client is displaying it as 2, and not that your DB saves it as such. You haven't mentioned which database software you use, but I can't imagine that there's any server out there that won't store the `FLOAT` and `DECIMAL` types as such.

Comment: Column type decimal(6,1) should suffice.

Comment: How i see this...At display time i need to check if the number is whole.If yes {echo $number.'.0';} else {echo $number}
Do you have a cleaner ideea?:-?

Comment: @user3647971 That did it! Post it as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In create statement use datatype as `" engine DECIMAL(2,1) "`, then you can store a decimal value in the database (this is for MySQL Only).

> Documentation: [**fixed point type**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fixed-point-types.html)

Comment: As @user3647971 said in comments, decimal(6,1) can do the work, as well as decimal (3,1).
Can you explain to me what's the difference between decimal(10,1)(default) and (6,1) or (3,1)?

Answer (score 1):

Please use decimal datatype with Length/Values of 10,1 or 2,1 or 3,2 as per your value based

```
`amt` DECIMAL(10,1) NOT NULL
```